# How to install specific version of sphinx via apt-get on Ubuntu precise?

Tags: apt, sphinx

I want to install a specific version of sphinx on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.  I'm using Chef but I think that's incidental to my question.

I know generally one can do:

```
apt-get install some_package=version
```

However I cannot seem to find the correct version number/name for sphinx 2.2.4.  I have tried the following:

```
2.2.4
2.2.4-4699-0ubuntu10
2.2.4-4699-0ubuntu10_amd64
```

And I get `Version '2.2.4-4699-0ubuntu10' for 'sphinxsearch' was not found` (or similiar).

You can see the package listed [here](https://launchpad.net/~builds/+archive/ubuntu/sphinxsearch-daily/+packages).  I have already added the PPA and updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `apt-cache show sphinx` show the same version numbers?

Comment: `apt-cache show sphinx` gave me `Unable to locate package sphinx`, as did `apt-cache policy sphinx`.  (Once I actually added the PPA successfully) `apt-cache show|policy sphinxsearch` gave version numbers like `2.2.4-4699-0ubuntu10`.

Comment: Ah, the package name is `sphinxsearch`, not `sphinx`... confusing when you state you want to update `sphinx` but you mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it turned out that adding the PPA had failed so its packages weren't available.

Adding the PPA failed because the `add-apt-repository` command wasn't available.  This was resolved by first `apt-get install python-software-properties`.

Here's the complete solution:

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y ppa:builds/sphinxsearch-daily
apt-get -y update

# inspect the available packages
apt-cache policy sphinxsearch

apt-get install -y sphinxsearch=2.2.4-4699-0ubuntu10
```